# Netlify, Lambdas, Stripe, and Googlebots

Tags: reactjs, api, stripe-payments, netlify, google-crawlers

Ive been working on an SPA with React that i have deployed on Netlify. The application uses stripe.js as a form of payment. While all of the functionality of stripe appears to be working fine on the user side, we are running into a problem with Google Search Console. It seems that the Googlebot Crawler is being blocked by the Stripe robots.txt file. basically the ultimate goal is to be approved for google adsense and after numerous rejections (even with prerendering and a lot more content added) we are still getting rejected. when we tried the google search console to see what google bot crawlers see we have absolutely no errors, the site is mobile friendly BUT we are getting this error that is shown below. While I obviously don't have any control over their use of Stripes robot.txt file, the Search console is also telling me this:

Message:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://m.stripe.com/6' from origin 'https://m.stripe.network' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Source:
https://m.stripe.network/inner.html#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.stateiqtest.org%2F&title=&referrer=&muid=NA&sid=NA&version=6&preview=false:0

The last thing i want to mention is all of the stripe functionality is accessed and called from a serverless Lambda function through netlify... I am confused why the CORS issue is a policy for the bot but not for users of the site? I am attaching my stripe lambda function call which I just enabled the cors policy for...   but once again ... why do i have to even do this? if im not getting errors in the console from the user side how come the bot can't access it? i have tried everything from changing my netlify.toml file to adding a robots.txt file which disallows the provided Stripe URL. any leads? let me know! your help is already appreciated ! :)

```
//client sides
import {loadStripe} from "@stripe/stripe-js"

export async function handleFormSubmission(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const form = new FormData(event.target);

  const data = {
    sku: form.get('sku'),
    quantity: Number(form.get('quantity')),
  };


  const response = await fetch('/.netlify/functions/create-checkout', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  }).then((res) => res.json())
  const stripe=await loadStripe(response.publishableKey);
  const {err}=await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    sessionId:response.sessionId
  })


  if(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

im honestly going to admit i haven't used stripe in a while and haven't had issues until now thus am revisiting code. here is another function that i believe makes the request and creates the stripe checkout...

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
const inventory = require('./data/products.json');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const { sku, quantity } = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const product = inventory.find((p) => p.sku === sku);
  const validatedQuantity = quantity > 0 && quantity < 2 ? quantity : 1;

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    billing_address_collection: 'required',
    success_url: `${process.env.URL}/success`,
    cancel_url: process.env.URL,
    line_items: [
      {
        name: 'Cognitive Analysis',
        currency:'USD',
        amount: 299,
        quantity: 1
      },
    ],
  });

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      sessionId: session.id,
      publishableKey: process.env.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY,
    }),
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST",
      }
  };
};
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I follow what you're trying to do here, but I expect that Stripe would block Google's ability to crawl a Checkout Session - is that where the issue is happening?

Comment: yes. from the user/client side stripe is working fine. basically we have been getting rejected by Google Adsense. we used the google search console to see how google bots crawl our website and noticed the google bot  is not able to access certain parts of our site (the stripe checkout page). it says it is blocked by stripe's robot.txt file but we are also getting this message:    Message: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://m.stripe.com/6' from origin 'https://m.stripe.network' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: btw these warnings are showing up in the google search console. i am not sure if the google bot that crawls with google search console even behaves the same way as the Adsense bot BUT IF IT does then this could explain why we are getting rejected over by adsense. my hunch is maybe the crawler is unable to access stripe checkout page & rejecting our site? we thought it was lack of content... we added MUCH more content and even had someone tell us the quality is fine but i have a hunch this crawl issue is the cause... hoping this error on search console is same as adsense issue w/ adsense bot

Comment: I’m also not even sure if this IS a problem. I’ve read thag it’s quite normal for payment gateways to be blocked by bots which I get. But it just concerns me that the search console says “unable to access certain parts of site” when crawling. I’m just unsure if this could be causing the Adsense bot to reject our site or if the bot knows it’s clearly a payment gateway. Adsense is insanely unclear and gives us no reason behin rejection. It used to say lack of content but we fixed that